# Convert ubyte[] to string in D

Tags: encoding, d

I am receiving a ubyte[] from an untrusted source and need to convert it to a utf-8 encoded string. How can I convert it and check that the bytes I was given are valid utf-8 data?
There does not seem to be a function in phobos that does this directly (ie takes a ubyte[] or a range of ubyte and converts it to a string or range of chars).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std.utf.validate`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_utf.html#.validate)?

And something like this?

```d
import std.stdio;
import std.utf;

void main()
{
    ubyte[] bytes = cast(ubyte[])"собака";
    writeln("bytes: ", bytes);

    string str = cast(string)bytes;
    writeln("string: ", str);

    validate(str);

    writeln("valid");
}
```

Application output:

```
bytes: [209, 129, 208, 190, 208, 177, 208, 176, 208, 186, 208, 176]
string: собака
valid
```